# Problema al ejecutar un chat en java

Tags: java, java-swing, hilos

Estoy haciendo un chat en java que va de un punto a otro y tengo un error al ejecutar ambos. Cuando los ejecuto uno por uno no hay error, pero cuando lo hago simultáneamente me lanza una excepción ´NullPonterException y cuando quiero cerrar el "Peer 2" no me deja y me lanza una excepción de puntero nulo. No sé si tenga que ver el nombre de los objetos DatagramSocket Les agradecería mucho su ayuda :).

Acá el código

```
import static java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Peer extends JFrame
{
   private final int PUERTO = 8080;
   //Etiquetas
   private JLabel etiHost;
   private JLabel etiPuerto;
   private JLabel etiMensaje;
   private JLabel etiMensajeRecibido;
   //Campos de texto
   private JTextField tfHost;
   private JTextField tfPuerto;
   private JTextField tfmensaje;
   private JTextField tfMensajeRecibido;
   //Boton de enviar
   private JButton btnEnviar;

//Sockets de emision y recepcion
private DatagramSocket miSocket = null;
//buffer para enviar el mensaje
byte[] mensaje;

public Peer(String nombre)
{
    super(nombre);
    setSize(300, 300);
    setLayout(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    initComponents();
}

private void initComponents()
{
    //etiquetas
    etiHost = new JLabel("Host");
    etiPuerto = new JLabel("Puerto");
    etiMensaje = new JLabel("Mensaje");
    etiMensajeRecibido = new JLabel("Mensaje recibido");

    //campos de texto
    tfHost = new JTextField();
    tfPuerto = new JTextField();
    tfmensaje = new JTextField();
    tfMensajeRecibido = new JTextField();

    //botton
    btnEnviar = new JButton("Enviar");

    getContentPane().add(etiHost);
    getContentPane().add(etiPuerto);
    getContentPane().add(etiMensaje);
    getContentPane().add(etiMensajeRecibido);

    getContentPane().add(tfHost);
    getContentPane().add(tfPuerto);
    getContentPane().add(tfmensaje);
    getContentPane().add(tfMensajeRecibido);

    getContentPane().add(btnEnviar);

    etiHost.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 25);
    etiPuerto.setBounds(10, 40, 100, 25);
    etiMensaje.setBounds(10, 70, 100, 25);
    etiMensajeRecibido.setBounds(10, 100, 100, 25);

    tfHost.setBounds(110, 10, 100, 25);
    tfPuerto.setBounds(110, 40, 100, 25);
    tfmensaje.setBounds(110, 70, 100, 25);
    tfMensajeRecibido.setBounds(110, 100, 100, 25);

    btnEnviar.setBounds(110, 150, 100, 25);

    try
    {
        miSocket = new DatagramSocket(PUERTO);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        ;
    }

    btnEnviar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
        {   

            if(tfHost.getText().equals("") || tfPuerto.getText().equals(""))
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debe ingresar host y/o puerto");

            else
            {
                try
                {
                    enviarMensaje();
                }
                catch(IOException e)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Intente de nuevo. Ocurrió un error en " + e.toString());
                }
                catch(NumberFormatException e)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El puerto debe de ser un numero entero");
                }
            }
        }
    });

    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt)
        {
            miSocket.close();
        }
    });

    try
    {
        miSocket = new DatagramSocket(PUERTO);
    }
    catch(Exception e) { ; }

    Thread d = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public synchronized void run()
        {
            while(true)
            {
                try
                {
                    while(true)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            miSocket = new DatagramSocket(PUERTO);
                        }
                        catch(Exception e) { ; }
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                        DatagramPacket datagrama = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
                        miSocket.receive(datagrama);
                        String mensaje = new String(buffer);
                        tfMensajeRecibido.setText(mensaje); //para ir incrementando el mensaje
                    }
                }
                catch(IOException e)
                {

                }
            }
        }
    });

    d.start();
}

private void enviarMensaje() throws IOException, NumberFormatException
{
    try
    {
        InetAddress miHost = InetAddress.getByName(tfHost.getText());
        int miPuerto = Integer.parseInt(tfPuerto.getText());
        byte[] buffer = tfmensaje.getText().getBytes();
        DatagramSocket miSocket = new DatagramSocket();
        DatagramPacket datagrama = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, miHost, miPuerto);
        miSocket.send(datagrama);
        miSocket.close();
    }catch(Exception e) { ; }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            new Peer("Un peer1").setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
}
```

El segundo "PEER"

```
import static java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Peer2 extends JFrame
 {
   private final int PUERTO = 8080;
   //Etiquetas
   private JLabel etiHost;
   private JLabel etiPuerto;
   private JLabel etiMensaje;
   private JLabel etiMensajeRecibido;
   //Campos de texto
   private JTextField tfHost;
   private JTextField tfPuerto;
   private JTextField tfmensaje;
   private JTextField tfMensajeRecibido;
   //Boton de enviar
   private JButton btnEnviar;

//Sockets de emision y recepcion
private DatagramSocket miSocket1 = null;
//buffer para enviar el mensaje
byte[] mensaje;

public Peer2(String nombre)
{
    super(nombre);
    setSize(300, 300);
    setLayout(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    initComponents();
}

private void initComponents()
{
    //etiquetas
    etiHost = new JLabel("Host");
    etiPuerto = new JLabel("Puerto");
    etiMensaje = new JLabel("Mensaje");
    etiMensajeRecibido = new JLabel("Mensaje recibido");

    //campos de texto
    tfHost = new JTextField();
    tfPuerto = new JTextField();
    tfmensaje = new JTextField();
    tfMensajeRecibido = new JTextField();

    //botton
    btnEnviar = new JButton("Enviar");

    getContentPane().add(etiHost);
    getContentPane().add(etiPuerto);
    getContentPane().add(etiMensaje);
    getContentPane().add(etiMensajeRecibido);

    getContentPane().add(tfHost);
    getContentPane().add(tfPuerto);
    getContentPane().add(tfmensaje);
    getContentPane().add(tfMensajeRecibido);

    getContentPane().add(btnEnviar);

    etiHost.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 25);
    etiPuerto.setBounds(10, 40, 100, 25);
    etiMensaje.setBounds(10, 70, 100, 25);
    etiMensajeRecibido.setBounds(10, 100, 100, 25);

    tfHost.setBounds(110, 10, 100, 25);
    tfPuerto.setBounds(110, 40, 100, 25);
    tfmensaje.setBounds(110, 70, 100, 25);
    tfMensajeRecibido.setBounds(110, 100, 100, 25);

    btnEnviar.setBounds(110, 150, 100, 25);

    try
    {
        miSocket1 = new DatagramSocket(PUERTO);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        ;
    }

    btnEnviar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
        {   

            if(tfHost.getText().equals("") || tfPuerto.getText().equals(""))
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debe ingresar host y/o puerto");

            else
            {
                try
                {
                    enviarMensaje();
                }
                catch(IOException e)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Intente de nuevo. Ocurrió un error en " + e.toString());
                }
                catch(NumberFormatException e)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El puerto debe de ser un numero entero");
                }
            }
        }
    });

    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt)
        {
            miSocket1.close();
        }
    });

    try
    {
        miSocket1 = new DatagramSocket(PUERTO);
    }
    catch(Exception e) { ; }

    Thread c = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public synchronized void run()
        {
            while(true)
            {
                try
                {
                    while(true)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            miSocket1 = new DatagramSocket(PUERTO);
                        }
                        catch(Exception e) { ; }
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                        DatagramPacket datagrama = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
                        miSocket1.receive(datagrama);
                        String mensaje = new String(buffer);
                        tfMensajeRecibido.setText(mensaje); //para ir incrementando el mensaje
                    }
                }
                catch(IOException e)
                {

                }
            }
        }
    });

    c.start();
}

private void enviarMensaje() throws IOException, NumberFormatException
{
    try
    {
                InetAddress miHost = InetAddress.getByName(tfHost.getText());
                int miPuerto = Integer.parseInt(tfPuerto.getText());
                byte[] buffer = tfmensaje.getText().getBytes();
                DatagramSocket miSocket1 = new DatagramSocket();
                DatagramPacket datagrama = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, miHost, miPuerto);
                miSocket1.send(datagrama);
                miSocket1.close();
    }catch(Exception e) { ; }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            new Peer("Un peer2").setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema principal no es una `NullPointerException`, la NPE es solamente daño colateral. Tu problema principal es este código:

```
                while(true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // aquí tratas de instar un DatagramSocket
                        miSocket1 = new DatagramSocket(PUERTO);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e) { ; } // aqui confias que eso funciona, pero...
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    DatagramPacket datagrama = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
                    // aquí tu socket es null, entonces la NPE
                    miSocket1.receive(datagrama);
                    String mensaje = new String(buffer);
                    tfMensajeRecibido.setText(mensaje); //para ir incrementando el mensaje
                }
```

Tu no puedes crear más que un socket escuchando en el mismo interfaz de red en el mismo puerto, y en tu ejemplo tratas de crear dos en  puerto 8080.

Eso hubieras discubierto por una `java.net.BindExceptionException`, antes que la `NullPointerException` hubiera occurido, pero te mandaste una bala en la propia rodilla:

**Escondiste tus errores!**

Dejando un catch vacío como `catch (Exception e) {}` (Si no quieres saber de tus errores, te puedes ahorrar el `;` también) es una muy **mala** idea, si no estas 100% seguro que ninguna excepción que pasa en esta parte te interrumpe el flujo. Que se tira una excepción que tiene cero impacto a tu flujo no es muy común.

Hasta que sabes **exactamente** que puedes ignorar alguna excepción en particular, **siempre** deja un `e.printStackTrace()` o algo parecido que te avisa donde las cosas se te van para el sur.

Además te pierdes la mejor parte del POO creando dos clases identicos, en vez de parametrizarlos y pasarles datos en el constructor. Olvidate de `Peer2` y cambia el constructor a:

```
private int puerto;

public Peer(String nombre, int puerto)
{
    super(nombre);
    this.puerto=puerto;
    setSize(300, 300);
    setLayout(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    initComponents();
}
```

Luego cambias el código para escuchar a mensajes a:

```
            try {
                miSocket1 = new DatagramSocket(puerto);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getClass().getName());
            }
```

Así puedes comprobar tu app instando:

```
new Peer("Peer 1", 8080).setVisible(true);
new Peer("Peer 2", 8081).setVisible(true);
```